# Как получить таблицы из базы данных содержащих нужное значение PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

В базе много таблиц. Мне нужно найти определенную и я не знаю как она называется, но я знаю одно из значений в ее столбцах. Можно ли как-то найти нужную таблицу?

Comment: [Посмотрите такой вопрос на основном stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql) , предложено несколько вариантов поиска.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант сделать дамп все базы, а потом в нем поиском по тексту найти нужное значение.

Если кроме значения знаете и название столбца, то по идее можно написать скрипт, который пройдется по всем таблицам, выяснит есть ли там такой столбец и если он есть, то сделает запрос по этому столбцу с известным вам значением.